# Why is there no cyclic layout issue for classes in C#?

Tags: c#, class, struct, circular-dependency, cyclic-reference

```
public struct Unit
{
    Unit u;
}
```

> Causes:
>
> Struct member 'Unit.u' of type 'Unit' causes a cycle in the struct
>   layout.

But

```
public class Unit
{
    Unit u;
}
```

compiles. I understand the problem I suppose. An endless cycle will be formed when referencing a `Unit` object since it will have to initialize another member `Unit` and so on. But why does the compiler restrict the problem just for `structs`? Doesn't the issue persist for `class` too? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is in terms of *layout*.

When `Unit` is a struct, any value for a `Unit` would have to contain another value of the same type (and thus the same size), ad infinitum. That's impossible. I suppose you could argue that with no other fields, the fields for `Unit` should take up no memory, so you *could* contain it within itself - but I believe the way the CLR works ensures that all structs take up at least 1 byte...

When `Unit` is a class, a `Unit` object only has to contain a *reference* to another `Unit` object. No storage problems, and the value can be null to start with.

Think of it this way: you can't have a house which contains another house constructed from the same blueprint, but you can certainly have a house which contains a piece of paper with a similar house's address on it...

Comment: @Jon, the house example is great indeed! :)

Comment: Succinctly explained in the last bit. +1

Comment: Oh god, when I answer the same question with Jon, my answer looks like pointless. Damn!

Comment: Is it correct to say that the Unit contains itself? It does not contain itself, but contains another Unit. It's just that a Unit contains a Unit contains a Unit... to infinity.

Comment: @Sahuagin yes you're right. Jon might edit it. But the point is driven home anyways :)

Comment: @Sahuagin: Any single value contains another value of the same type. Will edit to make the wording somewhat more bulletproof.

Comment: @Sahuagin: Jon is of course correct; to illustrate the point, consider the built-in structs. You cannot say `struct Int32 { private Int32 value; }` but from the CLR's perspective, an Int32 is precisely a struct whose sole field is an Int32. Obviously in order for that to be sensible, the CLR has to have special knowledge: that an Int32 is four bytes. It has no such special knowledge of the original poster's recursively-defined struct.

Comment: @EricLippert: I *very* nearly mentioned that (I started writing the edit then abandoned it), as it came up at CodeMash. I wasn't sure how public that was meant to be though :)

Answer (score 3):

Classes are reference types, so I imagine the difference is that in the `class` example, it only has to save a reference to another instance. For your `struct`, a value type, it would need to include the entire structure again, hence an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `struct` is automatically initialized with a value, so in your example a `Unit` value contains a `Unit` value, which contains a `Unit` value, which contains a `Unit` value, etc...

Your `class` example only initializes the reference to `null`, which does not have an infinite regress. You would however encounter a similar problem if you did the following:

```
class Unit
{
   Unit mUnit = new Unit();
}
```

Now, constructing a `Unit` constructs a `Unit`, which constructs a `Unit`, etc... In this case, you will encounter a runtime stack overflow exception if/when you try to instantiate a `Unit` object.

I thought that you might be able to avoid the `struct` issue by using a nullable type, but the problem remains. I believe this is due to the fact that a nullable `struct` is still instantiated when set to `null`.

Comment: Both your assumptions are wrong in fact. Edit it. With the first one I mean there isn't any compile time warning like as in for structs.

Comment: @nawfal can you be more specific?

Comment: I didn't say you would get a compile time warning I said you'd get a stack overflow, which you do.

Comment: Ok the first code is not so much of an issue because you're talking of something similar (yet different since its a runtime exception). But the second code doesn't compile either.

Comment: Please edit the incorrect info. Someone might downvote this otherwise. Nevertheless I see your point and gave me more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Struct` are `value type`. `Unit` can hold the value as itself? I think this is not posible.

But when `Unit` is `class`, `class` are `reference type`. `Unit` object can hold a *reference* to the another `Unit` object. It is fine.